# Aggregation of a strange looking table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ugly Table

```
Resource name       PROJECT WeekStarting            Monday  Tuesday Wednesday   Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday  ChargeRate
Dave Y              DELTA   2014-09-01 00:00:00.000 0       1       1           1           0       0               0   20.00
Dave Y              DELTA   2014-09-15 00:00:00.000 0       1       1           1           0       0               0   20.00
Dave Y              DELTA   2014-09-22 00:00:00.000 0       1       1           1           0       0               0   20.00
Dave Y              DELTA   2014-09-29 00:00:00.000 0       1       1           1           0       0               0   20.00
Dave Y              HOLIDAY 2014-09-08 00:00:00.000 1       1       1           1           1       0               0   0.00
Dave Y              HOLIDAY 2014-09-22 00:00:00.000 0       0       0           0           1       0               0   0.00
```

I have to get the following view for all individuals .

September 2014

```
Resource Name   Days Booked ( Days Worked - Holidays )    Total Rate 
   Dave Y            6      ( 12 - 6)                          120
```

And also for October and November.

How to transform the ugly table into the below table via sql in one query ?

Comment: Can you explain where you get your desired results from?  `Days Worked - Holidays`, where does `12-6` come from?  And where does your `Total Rate` come from?

Comment: The answer is: you should write some code for this. What did you try so far?

Comment: Days worked in September - Adding all the ones from the first 4 rows =12   Holidays in September - Adding all the ones in row 5 and 6 where the Project name is Holidays. =6  . The total rate is the number of days worked times the rate , so that is 6 times 20 = 120 pounds .

Comment: select Resource name , PROJECT , WeekStarting, ( sum (Monday)+sum (Tuesday) + sum(Wednesday) +sum(Thursday) +sum(Friday)+sum(Saturday)+sum(Sunday)) as [Total Days in Week],  ChargeRate
from [Ugly Table]
group by Resource name , PROJECT , WeekStarting, ChargeRate

This gives me RESOURCE, PROJECT , RECORD FOR A WEEK, NOS OF DAYW WORKED IN WEEK AND CHARGE RATE .

Comment: This gives me weekly records but does not take into account holidays or aggregate everything together to get what I am looking for ....

Comment: I have a déjà vu, did you ask this question before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explain where 'Total Rate' is coming from.  But this is one way to do the rest of it.

```
SELECT
    cast(Datepart(m, WeekStarting) as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(Datepart(yyyy, WeekStarting) as varchar(4)) as [Month]
    , ResourceName
    , SUM (CASE WHEN PROJECT = 'HOLIDAY' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END * (
        Monday + Tuesday + Wednesday + Thursday + Friday + Saturday + Sunday)) AS DaysBooked

FROM
    #UglyTable

GROUP BY
    ResourceName
    , Datepart(m, WeekStarting)
    , Datepart(yyyy, WeekStarting)
```